# Can't read raw POST body data - how to do this in this example?

Tags: php, http, http-post

I'm setting an API for my server for another developer. I'm currently using `Flash AIR` to send POST data to my server, and simply extract the variables as in

```
$command = $_POST['command'].
```

However, he's not using Flash, and is sending data like so:

```
https://www.mysite.com POST /api/account.php?command=login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: close

command=login
params {"pass":"12345678","token":"","appID":"theirApp","user":"johnnyb","ver":"2.0","Library_ID":"1"}
```

My server is returning him an error saying that the 'command' parameter is missing.

What do I need to do my end to extract the $_POST var 'command' from his above data?

I've tried `file_get_contents('php://input')` and `http_get_request_body()`, but although they don't error, they don't show anything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Content-Type should be www-form-urlencoded"  from @Cole (correct answer)

More info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

Answer (score 2):

The request claims that it is sending JSON.

> Content-Type: application/json

However, this:

> ```
> command=login
> params {"pass":"12345678","token":"","appID":"theirApp","user":"johnnyb","ver":"2.0","Library_ID":"1"}
> ```

… is not JSON.

If you get rid of everything before the `{` then it would be JSON and you should be able to read it with `file_get_contents('php://input')` (and could then pass it through [a decoder](http://php.net/json_decode).

> I've tried `file_get_contents('php://input')` and `http_get_request_body()` … they don't show anything.

They should work.

> When I print out `file_get_contents('php://input')` for the comms … I get command=login, yet...

I thought you said you didn't get anything

> `if(!isset($_POST['command']))`

`$_POST` will only be populated for the two standard HTML form encoding methods. If you are using JSON then it won't be automatically parsed, you have to do it yourself (with valid JSON input (so the additional data would need to be encoded in the JSON text with the rest of the data)), `file_get_contents('php://input')` and `decode_json`).

Answer (score 1):

The command parameter needs to be part of the data, and the whole thing should be valid JSON. As is, `command=login`, it is not valid JSON.

Add it to the `params` object or make a containing object, like

```
{
 command:'login',
 params :{"pass":"12345678","token":"","appID":"theirApp","user":"johnnyb","ver":"2.0","Library_ID":"1"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cole. Still getting the same error. To make it simpler, I've cut out the params var, so we're just dealing with trying to extract the command var. When I print out file_get_contents('php://input') for the comms from both Flash and the other dev's code (FYI - he's NOT using PHP, writing it in C++, not even using a library, except for CFNetwork on mac), I get command=login, yet... if(!isset($_POST['command'])) sendError('command_missing'); only sends the error back for his code. How does someone hand-coding an "HTTP POST" structure his headers and/or body so it ends up PHP $_POST vars?

Comment: @Shaun On second thought this is all madness. Servers do not accept JSON encoded POST data. It needs to be mime type www-form-urlencoded and sent as key-value pairs.

Comment: Ahh - I'm not asking about how to modify the server to accept the data, I'm asking how does the C++ CLIENT formulate his post such that the server accepts it into my $_POST key-value variables?

The server is working just fine, for clients running flash and using that library to communicate.  But exactly what is the format of the output that the C++ client must create?  What *exactly* does "mime type www-form-urlencoded and sent as key-value pairs" LOOK like?  A concrete example would really help if someone is able to post one. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Shaun Content-Type should be www-form-urlencoded, not application/json. And then it looks like command=whatever&params=whatever with all the special characters URL encoded (just do a search for that...). I would be surprised if there's not a library for that, but I don't know C++. You can send a JSON payload, to be deciphered by the server... But not as content type JSON in a post.

Comment: Thanks Cole - I'll pass this info on to the Dev

Comment: @shaun I suggest to set up a form in a browser and submit to your server... Then inspect the request.

Comment: Hey Cole. Your clue about  www-form-urlencoded solved the problem (although I never asked him how, as we excitedly continued with the api coding!). He said he looked up http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1 - and did that. So thank you mate!!!!!

Comment: @shaun awesome, glad I was able to help!